# how to handle this error in cakephp 1.3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

i use pregmatch to extract image name from article text ...so when admin dont add image in the article he see this error

```
Notice (8): Uninitialized string offset: 0 [CORE\cake\libs\view\helpers\html.php, line 608]
```

anyway to stop show this error if the admin don't added image

```
<?php
  echo $html->link( $html->image($imagename,array('height'=>'250px', 'width'=>'280px')),array('action' => 'view', $article['Article']['id']),array('escape' => false));
   ?>
```

Comment: the answer is this code Configure::write('debug', 0);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're parsing the article text to get the image link and the display it somewhere in your view.

Check before echo

```
<?php
if(isset($imagename) && $imagename != ""){
   echo $html->link( $html->image($imagename,array('height'=>'250px','width'=>'280px')),array('action' => 'view',$article['Article']['id']),array('escape' => false));
}
?>
```